# How would I charge to create an entry (e.g. in Solspace Calendar)

Tags: members, solspace-calendar, subscriptions, membrr

I want to build a site that allows subscribe, then book time slots in a calendar. Booking a slot will cost an amount based on criteria the member selects in a form. I'm thinking the subscription part of the site will be built with Membrr, and the calendar will be Solspace Calendar.

The part I'm not sure about is how to charge users to book a slot (effectively charging to create an entry?).

Has anyone done something similar, or have ideas regarding how I might implement this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if you got this figured out yet on your own but here's what I would do: Membrr is not actively maintained (last I checked), but I know DevDemon has a new addon called [Subscriptions](http://www.devdemon.com/expressionengine-addons/subscriptions) that looks killer. I haven't used it yet but it seems like it would do everything and then some that you are asking.

But if you don't need actual subscriptions, but just one-off allowing of creating entries I would use [Charge](https://devot-ee.com/add-ons/charge). I have used this in the past and what I did was created a AJAX request to a hidden template URL on the "receipt" page. What this did was created a new entry with that user as the author, then in the list of pages they were allowed to edit, I limited these to the ones by CURRENT_USER.

I hope this helps. You can hit me up if you want me to send you some code snippets.